# agregar a una lista el elemento True de un condicional multiple

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist, function, formato-condicional

mi pregunta es la siguiente:
en el siguiente código(x y i z son funciones que modifican un string)

```py
if x(nombre) or y(nombre) or z(nombre) in lista_1:
    lista.append(nombre)
```

hay alguna manera de agregar en la lista el resultado que sea True sin escribir una condición para cada función? Me seria de mucha ayuda(en el programa son muchas mas)

Gracias!

Comment: No he entendido muy bien tu pregunta, podrías agregar un ejemplo de que es lo que quieres?

Comment: Pues es simple, pero nose si posible, si usas un condicional como este donde las diferentes funciones darán distintos resultados, uno de ellos sera True, es decir el que me de el condicional por bueno. Sin embargo si yo pongo append y la variable que esta modificando, en la lista se agregara la variable sin modificar.

podría hacer lo siguiente para tener el resultado que yo quiero:
```python
if x(nombre) in lista_1:
    lista_1.append(x(nombre))
elif y(nombre) in lista_1:
    lista_1.append(y(nombre))

y siguiendo, sin embargo esto me ocuparía como 60 lineas d código. Busco resumirlo

Comment: Hay un problema de logica. Si una función llega a devolver True, y agregas el resultado de esa función a la lista, lo que se agregará será el objeto True. Estás seguro de que las funciones deberían de devolver True? O deberían (y devuelven) algo que es considerado verdadero por Python?

Comment: Si me referia a que es considerado True, no True en si. Perdon por expresarme mal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solución

Esto se puede hacer con un bucle for que:

- recorra la lista de funciones (las funciones también son objetos cuando no se coloca parentesis a su derecha)
- aplique cada función a la cadena
- vea si lo devuelto por dicha función es verdadero
- Si la condición es cierta, agregue el elemento a la lista y finalize el bucle con break (ya que ya no hace más falta seguir aplicando funciones si una devolvió verdadero).

A continuación, pondremos esto a prueba usando 3 funciones que devuelvan un nuevo string o False.

```
def is_upper(string):
    if(string.isupper()):
        return f"upper_{string}"
    else:
        return False

def is_lower(string):
    if(string.islower()):
        return f"lower_{string}"
    else:
        return False
    
def is_title(string):
    if(string.istitle()):
        return f"title_{string}"
    else:
        return False

string_list = ["hola", "HOLA", "Hola"]
lista = []

for string in string_list:
    for func in [is_upper, is_lower, is_title]:
        rta = func(string)

        if(rta):
            lista.append(rta)
            break

print(string_list)
print(lista)
```

Produce...

```
['hola', 'HOLA', 'Hola']
['lower_hola', 'upper_HOLA', 'title_Hola']
```

#### Conclusión

Cuando ves que tus condicionales se vuelven muy largos y/o hay una cantidad variable de comparaciones parecidas que hacer, recurrir a un bucle for junto a un iterable es una buena opción.
Python nos ofrece ciertos atajos, que a veces hasta resultan mejores que estos maravillosos bucles for.

- [all](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#all) y [any](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#any). all devuelve verdadero cuando todos los items de un iterable son verdaderos y any si uno de ellos lo es. Es muy util combinarlos con [comprensiones de generador](https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/comprension-de-listas-y-otras-colecciones/)
- El [operador in](https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/operadores-basicos-en-python-con-ejemplos/#:%7E:text=Operadores%20de%20Pertenencia,-Un%20operador%20de&text=in%20devuelve%20True%20si%20el,En%20caso%20contrario%20devuelve%20False.) generalmente devuelve verdadero cuando un elemento se encuentra en un iterable (en realidad, el comportamiento de in, mas allá de devolver un booleano, depende del método `__contains__` del objeto, pero el antes mencionado es el comportamiento habitual). Yo aprendí que `a in ("a", "b", "c")` es mejor de escribir que `a == "a" or a == "b" or a == "c"`

Comment: No sabia que se podían recorrer las funciones(soy bastante novato), definitivamente me ha resultado muy útil tu respuesta.
Muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada Andreu c: